# Is there a way to solve equation of this form?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2 + 
   + 
  g(y) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + h(y) = 0$$

How to solve this differential equation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$f'(y)^2 + g(y) f(y) + h(y) = 0$$

Solving the quadratic,
$$f'(y) = \frac{-1}{2}g(y) \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{g(y)^2 - 4 h(y)}$$

Integrating both sides,

$$f(y) = C -\frac{1}{2} \int_{y_0}^y g(s) \, ds \pm \frac{1}{2} \int_{y_0}^y \sqrt{g(s)^2 - 4 h(s)} \, ds$$